# In vb.net, how do I access a public function in a module from within a user control?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How can I access public functions from a user control the same way I can access public functions from a form? The public functions are in a utility module.

Comment: This was a really dumb question. I copied utility.vb into the project, but was distracted and did not include in the project (right-click, include in project). Later I couldn't figure out why the functions were not visible everywhere. When I got home I remembered, but I had already done the SO posting :(

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you have a module named `SpecialUtility` which is in `SomeProject.Utilities` namespace.

```
' Without "Global." prefix the "SomeProject.Utilities" namespace 
' would be placed under the project's default namespace.
' If your project's default namespace was "SomeProject" then 
' you could write only "Namespace Utilities" in this case.
Namespace Global.SomeProject.Utilities
    Module SpecialUtility
        Public Sub DoSomething()
            Console.WriteLine("Doing something")
        End Sub
    End Module
End Namespace
```

You should import the namespace of that utility module in the user control.

```
Imports SomeProject.Utilities

Public Class SomeUserControl
    Private Sub SomeAction()
        ' Now you can call DoSomething() method from SpecialUtility module.
        DoSomething()
    End Sub
End Class
```